# Excel 97-2003 Macro does not work in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel file that was done in Excel 97-2003. It contains a macro. The macro runs fine in Excel 2010 but have now had to convert to Excel 2013 and the macro does not work.
I am only a basic user on macros; can someone point me in the right direction?
I get "**Error 9**". I tried to understand the debugger but I could not figure it out.

```
            AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
            AllowFormattingRows:=True

            Sheets("Print-Send").Select
            Cells(counter, "D").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ("")
            Sheets(model).Select
            Sheets(model).Move _
                After:=Workbooks("Compressed CPC.xls").Sheets(3) 'error here
            Range("B4").Select
            Selection.ClearComments
            Range("A8").Select
            Selection.ClearComments
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: We can not help you without the complete macro code. Paste it at pastebin.com and edit the link to your question. If there are multiple modules, paste & link every module as separate link

Comment: Or at least edit your question and post the section that's throwing the error. As-is, this is WAY to vague.

Comment: Sorry Guys. being blocked from pastebin.com.  is it ok to post the txt from the debugger here?

Comment: An* is in front of the line the debugger says is bad                                       AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True
        Sheets("Print-Send").Select
        Cells(counter, "D").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ("")
        Sheets(model).Select
       *Sheets(model).Move After:=Workbooks("Compressed CPC.xls").Sheets(3)
        Range("B4").Select
        Selection.ClearComments
        Range("A8").Select
        Selection.ClearComments
    End If
    counter = counter + 1
Loop

End With

Comment: Please edit it into your question, and use the code formatting features of the editor.

Comment: Giving us the incorrect line isn't going to be perfect for troubleshooting as it may or may not use things that are properly defined or used previous to being called. Please post your entire module.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the limited code you posted, I have some guesses

- Do you have the workbook "Comproessed CPC.xls" open when the code is run?
- Does the workbook "Compressed CPC.xls" have 3 sheets in it?

And doing some further research it looks like `Error 9` may have to do with getting data from a closed workbook. As found in an article from www.excelsuperstar.com titled "[VBA Runtime Error 9 – Data From A Closed Workbook](http://excelsuperstar.com/2012/01/vba-error-9-data-from-a-closed-workbook/)"